# Login WP - Connect single field to an external api

Tags: custom-field, login, api

I made a plugin to allow wordpress login with external api.

Everything works, now what I have to do is that when a user logs in for the first time, the plugin checks to see if it is already present on wp, and where it was not already present, it creates a new user by taking behind username, email and password.

The new user is created but I would like it to bring with it also the id field from the external api saving it in an ACF field.

This is the code created so far:

```
<?php

/************************************
 * API Authentication
 ************************************/
add_filter('authenticate', 'au_auth', 10, 3);

/**
 * Calls external API when user logs in to Wordpress
 *
 * @param $user
 * @param $username
 * @param $password
 * @return bool|false|object|WP_Error|WP_User
 */
function au_auth($user, $username, $password)
{
    $options = get_option('au_options');
    $endpoint = $options['au_apiurl'];

    $user_email_key = 'email';
    $password_key = 'password';

    // Makes sure there is an endpoint set as well as username and password
    if (!$endpoint || $user !== null || (empty($username) && empty($password))) {
        return false;
    }

    // Check user exists locally
    $user_exists = wp_authenticate_username_password(null, $username, $password);

    if ($user_exists && $user_exists instanceof WP_User) {
        $user = new WP_User($user_exists);
        return $user;
    }

    // Build the POST request
    $login_data = array(
        $user_email_key => $username,
        $password_key => $password
    );

    $auth_args = array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'headers' => array(
            'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        ),
        'sslverify' => false,
        'body' => $login_data
    );


    $response = wp_remote_post($endpoint, $auth_args);

    // Token if success; Not used right now
    $response_token = json_decode($response['response']['token'], true);

    $response_code = $response['response']['code'];
    if ($response_code == 400) {
        // User does not exist, send back an error message
        $user = new WP_Error('denied', __("<strong>Error</strong>: Your username or password are incorrect."));
    } else if ($response_code == 200) {
        // External user exists, try to load the user info from the WordPress user table
        $userobj = new WP_User();
        // Does not return a WP_User object but a raw user object
        $user = $userobj->get_data_by('email', $username);
        if ($user && $user->ID) {
            // Attempt to load the user with that ID
            $user = new WP_User($user->ID);
        }
    } else {
        // The user does not currently exist in the WordPress user table.
        // Setup the minimum required user information
        $userdata = array(
            'user_email' => $username,
            'user_login' => $username,
            'user_pass' => $password
        );
        // A new user has been created
        $new_user_id = wp_insert_user($userdata);
        // Assign editor role to the new user (so he can access protected articles)
        wp_update_user(
            array(
                'ID' => $new_user_id,
                'role' => 'editor'
            )
        );
        // Load the new user info
        $user = new WP_User ($new_user_id);
    }
}
// Useful for times when the external service is offline
remove_action('authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_username_password', 20);

return $user;
}
```

Anyone have any way how to help me?

Comment: And what exactly is your question? Your code is already quite sophisticated, what is the problem with returning data from the API and saving it in addition to the user?

Comment: I would like that when I create a user, it also brings with it the user id present on the external api, saving it in a simple custom field "external_user_id"

Comment: Does the API return the value that you want? If so, what is stopping you, from using it to save it? If not, how are you gonna get the required value?

Comment: In reality this is precisely what I do not understand how to develop it, also because it is the first time that I find myself facing a request of this type and therefore I am looking for someone who can help me in some way

Comment: Is this API controlled by you or something external? Can edit your question to show an example resonse (e.g. `var_dump($response);` or from their API spec).?

Comment: This API is controlled externally by another company and I have no way to manage it.
Their field response, which I need to import during login, is this JSON:
{
  "Id": 80131,
  "Email": "john@doe.com",
  "Password": "pall"
}
Everything okay with regards to emails and passwords.
Only the id is missing

Comment: Is the field created in ACF ? [ACF Docs User Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/user/) , the [documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/) states you can update a field using **update_field($selector, $value, [$post_id]);**

Comment: Yes, I managed to move on but now I'm stuck here

"$ new_user_id = wp_insert_user ($ userdata);
            $ value = "";
            // get value from response you want to set
            update_field ('field_60084ad3970a8', $ value, 'user _'. $ new_user_id); "

I'm trying to figure out how to define the $ value field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize but I only now have a way to post my solution, maybe it can be useful to someone.

Here is my solution to the problem:

```
$new_user_id = wp_insert_user($userdata);
$value = json_decode($response['body'], true)['Id'];
// get value from response you want to set
update_field('field_60084ad3970a8', $value, 'user_'.$new_user_id);
```